# Subtract one dataframe from another, element wise, in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Element wise subtraction of dataframes in python pandas

The following works, but I was surprised that I needed to use `numpy` to do
this.

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

csv = '''\
pool,employee,xd1,xd2,xd1_bar,xd2_bar
1,a,-5.25,-3.92,-4.25,-3.42
1,b,-4.25,-3.92,-4.25,-3.42
1,c,-4.25,-2.92,-4.25,-3.42
1,d,-3.25,-2.92,-4.25,-3.42
2,e,-1.25,-0.92,-0.5,-0.16999999999999998
2,f,-1.25,1.08,-0.5,-0.16999999999999998
2,g,-0.25,0.08,-0.5,-0.16999999999999998
2,h,0.75,-0.92,-0.5,-0.16999999999999998
3,i,3.75,3.08,4.75,3.58
3,j,4.75,2.08,4.75,3.58
3,k,4.75,4.08,4.75,3.58
3,l,5.75,5.08,4.75,3.58
'''

data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv))

c1 = ["xd1", "xd2"]
c2 = ["xd1_bar", "xd2_bar"]

data_sub = data.join(
    pd.DataFrame(np.array(data[c1]) - np.array(data[c2]), columns=["x1_dev", "x2_dev"])
)
```

I expected the following to work:

```py
data[c1].cub(data[c2])
```

Comment: what is c1 c2 here

Answer (score 2):

They way you did here is correct ,since the `pandas` `dataframe` subtract will match the `column` and `index` , since you have different `column` and `index` for the c1 and c2

Kindly fix your output ,adding the `index` , since new dataframe , index will be range index, but your original one may not , you may not want to lost the information after join

```
data_sub = data.join(
    pd.DataFrame(np.array(data[c1]) - np.array(data[c2]), columns=["x1_dev", "x2_dev"], index=data.index)
)
```

Comment: An alternative: `data.join(np.subtract(data[c1],data[c2]),rsuffix='_dev')`